# PDFCleanUpProcessor just remove text

Tags: java, itext

Is there a way to get the PDFCleanUpProcessor from Itext to just remove text and not other items?

The code i've got here removes part of a table border as well as the text from the PDF

I guess thats because its replacing the text with the White Rectangle defined in the cleanuplocations list?

Can i perhaps use a blank rectangle instead of white.

I don't want to remove the table border, just any text found within the rectangle area

```
List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();            
for (int x = 1; x <= pagecount; x++) {                                
   if(x == pages.get(rectscount))  {                    
   Rectangle rect = rects.get(rectscount)
   cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(x, rect,BaseColor.WHITE));                    
   rectscount++;                
   }            
}            //System.out.println(cleanUpLocations.size());            
PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);            
cleaner.cleanUp();
```

Comment: The `PDFCleanUpProcessor` is designed for redaction purposes. Thus, it tries to remove all information in the clean-up locations. Nonetheless, it is open source, so you can try and change it to only remove certain information from there.